# Python Summarizing Arrays of Objects

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

```py
arr = [{'red': {'weight': 50}}, {'blue': {'weight': 60}}, {'red': {'weight': 70}}]
```

Let's say we want to summarize this array with the following expected output:

```py
output = [{'color': 'red', 'count': 2, 'total': 120, 'min': 50, 'max': 70, 'mean': 60},
          {'color': 'blue', 'count': 1, 'total': 60, 'min': 60, 'max': 60, 'mean': 60}]
```

Or alternatively:

```py
output = {'red':{'count': 2, 'total': 120, 'min': 50, 'max': 70, 'mean': 60},
          'blue':{'count': 1, 'total': 60, 'min': 60, 'max': 60, 'mean': 60}}
```

What I have tried:

```py
>>> {list(i.items())[0][0]:[list(j.items())[0][0] for j in arr].count(list(i.items())[0][0]) for i in arr}
{'red': 2, 'blue': 1}
```

```py
>>> [{list(i.items())[0][0]:{'count': [list(j.items())[0][0] for j in arr].count(list(i.items())[0][0])} for i in arr}]
[{'red': {'count': 2}, 'blue': {'count': 1}}]
```

```py
>>> [{'color': list(i.items())[0][0],'count': [list(j.items())[0][0] for j in arr].count(list(i.items())[0][0])} for i in arr]
[{'color': 'red', 'count': 2}, {'color': 'blue', 'count': 1}, {'color': 'red', 'count': 2}]
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense--your data summary contains more information that the data it's summarizing. Is it possible to restate your question? You may find it easier to refrain from using one liners and to instead write some loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group the list by color (just need to sort the list first) *(The best/easiest key I could think of was to just use tuple on the dicts)* then loop through and generate the list. `statistics.mean` is also an easy way to get the mean of a collection of numbers:

```
from itertools import groupby
from statistics import mean

arr = [{'red': {'weight': 50}}, {'blue': {'weight': 60}}, {'red': {'weight': 70}}]

output = []
for (k, *_), g in groupby(sorted(arr, key=tuple), key=tuple):
    all_vals = [d[k]['weight'] for d in g]
    output.append({'color': k, 'count': len(all_vals), 'total': sum(all_vals), 'min': min(all_vals), 'max': max(all_vals), 'mean': mean(all_vals)})
```

---

```
[{'color': 'blue', 'count': 1, 'total': 60, 'min': 60, 'max': 60, 'mean': 60},
 {'color': 'red', 'count': 2, 'total': 120, 'min': 50, 'max': 70, 'mean': 60}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just collect a list of the `'weight'` values and summarise them:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import statistics

def summarise(weights):
     return {'count': len(weights), 'total': sum(weights), 'min': min(weights), 'max': max(weights), 'mean': statistics.mean(weights)}

arr = [{'red': {'weight': 50}}, {'blue': {'weight': 60}}, {'red': {'weight': 70}}]

output = defaultdict(list)
for d in arr:
    for k in d:
        output[k].append(d[k]['weight'])
output = {k:summarise(weights) for (k,weights) in output.items()}
print(output)
```

Output:

```
{'red': {'count': 2, 'total': 120, 'min': 50, 'max': 70, 'mean': 60}, 
'blue': {'count': 1, 'total': 60, 'min': 60, 'max': 60, 'mean': 60}}
```